# Android AsyncTask with JSON Parsing error

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, wcf

**Error coming in this section:**

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(0);
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        Log.i("id",id);
    }
}
```

**------- Webservice Result---**

> {"GetDataResult":{"ID":8,"Name":"Foo Bar"}}
>   Working Link - http://127.0.0.1/WcfService4/Service1.svc/getData/?key=8

Provide the better solution for solving this.

Comment: Isn't 127.0.0.1 localhost? how are we supposed to access that link?

Comment: "Provide the better solution for solving this".. So now StackOverflow works for you huh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you havn't use your JSONArray object

```
JSONArray mainfoodlist = null;


    tipshealth = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

        // looping through All RESPONSE
        for (int i = 0; i < tipshealth.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobj = tipshealth.getJSONObject(i);
        tipHealth = jsonobj.getString(KEY_HEALTHTIPS);

        listhealthtips.add(tipshealth.getJSONObject(i).getString("tips"));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the problem comes from this section:

```
user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(0);
```

you get a `JOSNObject user` but you never used it.

I guess this is probably what you mean:

```
user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
```